# Does listening with an ear to the ground actually work?

Tags: survival

In movies, sometimes the character will put an ear to the ground and then hear people moving a long ways away [example](https://youtu.be/hDkvpZRZ_rE?t=16).

Does this actually work in the wild at all or is it just insufficient for anything short of a <s>horde of orcs</s> herd of buffalo?

Comment: Related at Skeptics [Do trackers hold their ears to the ground?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28858/do-trackers-hold-their-ears-to-the-ground)

Comment: ["Put your ear to the ground because that way you will eliminate the acoustic impedance mismatch and thus get a better sound transfer"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28858/do-trackers-hold-their-ears-to-the-ground) It only works when listening for a massive herd of Buffalo (which you tend to feel before you see anyways) or listening for incoming trails on railroad tracks.

Comment: It does work for railroad tracks.  I remember trying this as a kid.  I'm really skeptical that it is useful for hearing distant animals thru the ground.

Comment: ... but do make sure it's not a high-speed railroad track!

Answer (score 2):

If there is a herd of buffalo you will hear them sooner by listening at the ground, then in the air.

**BUT** only if there is lot of them, making a large impact.  A single animal or even a few is unlikely to have enough energy to transfer sound any distance in the earth.

> In a solid, the particles are even closer together and linked by chemical bonds so the wave travels even faster than it does in either liquid or air, but you need quite a lot of energy to start the wave at the beginning. [source (sciencelearn.org)](https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/572-sound-on-the-move)

Related sister site question [Do trackers hold their ears to the ground?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28858/45610)